# Can you run Craft CP on one webserver and serve the front end content on a separate one?

Tags: server, multi-domain

Much of my work is for a corporate organisation, and there is some resistance to having the CP of a CMS externally exposed. Is it possible to run the Craft CP on one internal (not available outside the network) webserver, and the front end on a separate webserver in the external DMZ which has its access to the CP turned off? Both would talk to the same database (I can see how this could work for two full versions). This is how we run our homegrown CMS which also stores all assets (CSS, JS, templates, images and PDFs) in the database, so I know I would have to find a solution for that, but I am imaging a CDN would solve that problem. What are the technical and licensing issues that need to be addressed? I want to ditch the homegrown CMSes in use, for Craft.

It isn't just the CP that would only be available inside. I want to make all the end user form data be accessible for view and 'office use' update as well i.e. so the form submissions are managed internally only.

Also, I might want to expose separate Sections as standalone websites (these are small 6-10 page medium term sites for conferences, but sometimes have their own domain. The form submissions would be consolidated). These separate sites would all be on the same external server.

Comment: Paying for more than one licence is not a problem.

Comment: I suppose this answers one of my questions re disabling the CP: 
http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4877/can-i-disable-the-control-panel

Comment: Oops I am finding the answers after I asked the question despite some (not hard enough) searching before hand:
http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/38/how-can-i-run-the-control-panel-from-a-separate-domain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this question was resolved via some extended sleuthing in the comments above:

- [Can I disable the control panel?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4877/can-i-disable-the-control-panel)
- [How can I run the Control Panel from a separate domain?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/38/how-can-i-run-the-control-panel-from-a-separate-domain)

Overall, it looks like the answer is yes, however some part of the solution lies in settings around the server environment and routing rules outside of Craft.